javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileIniti
We are using jMeter 5.5 & JMS Publisher addon to publish messages to relevant queues via AMPQ.
I have installed the following libraries/packages within jMeter config, and installed Java 11 on environment using guidance found online:

geronimo-jms_2.0_spec-1.0-alpha-2.jar
jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
proton-j-0.34.1.jar
qpid-jms-client-1.6.0.jar
qpid-proton-j-extensions-1.2.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
slf4j-simple-1.7.36.jar

Endpoints are specified within the jndi.properties file (which are correct), however seem to be facing the following error:
Response message:javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory]

Wondering if anybody could shed some light on how to resolve, or point me in the direction of some resolution steps? I believe the issue could lie somewhere within the packages/libraries installed, and their necessary dependents.

You clearly don't have the jar file containing the class org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory on your classpath. Put this class on your classpath and the problem will be resolved. That said, that class may not actually exist which means you need to change your configuration to use the right classname.

BTW, why are you using such an old version of the Qpid JMS client? The current release is 1.12.1 if you're still stuck using javax.jms packages.

Hi Justin, apologies for the beginner question. How am I able to add to classpath/change configuration?
We are using old version due to legacy system

It looks you don't have qpid-jms-client in your JMeter Classpath so please download it (and all its eventual transitive dependencies)
Once done restart JMeter, its absolutely required to pick up any changes in the Classpath.
Also be aware that according to JMeter Best Practices you should always use the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.6 or whatever is the latest stable version available at JMeter Downloads page

Hi Ivan, I have the qpid-jms-client-1.12.1.jar sat within C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-jmeter-5.5\lib
